# Can you make a webpage scroll from left to right instead of top to bottom?

Tags: css, scroll, multiple-columns

Is there a way you can make a web page that is divided into columns that will scroll from left to right rather than top to bottom? So that you got

```
x x x x x
x ... ..x ... ... ... ...
x ... ..x ... ... ... ...
x ... ..x ... ... ... ...
x ... ..x ... ... ... ...
x x x x x
```

Instead of

```
x x x x x
x ... ..x
x ... ..x
x ... ..x
x ... ..x
x x x x x
  ... ...
  ... ...
  ... ...
  ... ...
  ... ...
  ... ...
```

If that made sense... In other words, I'd like text to stop at the bottom of the browser window, and then continue in a new column and have this happen "infinitely" until there is no more content.

**Added** a screen shot below to explain better. You see the text goes on below the screen at the bottom. I'd like that which is below the screen to appear at the top, next to the first verse. What I'm trying to do is to have a whole song fit on one screen (which they usually would, especially on a wide screen monitor), without having to do a lot of flimsy math and calculations or changes in the markup. It's currently all in a `pre` tag, but I suppose that could be switched as long as the chords can match up with the word they're at (so monospace font etc). I'm looking for some magic CSS basically, if it even exists :)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can... but should you?  Users typically do not like websites that behave this way.  Not sure about everyone else, but my mouse wheel doesn't work with horizontal scrolling websites unless I'm pointing right at the scroll bar.

Comment: In general, most definitely not! But this is a special case where I'm trying to fit as much as possible on a single screen. I'm trying to avoid the scrolling all together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for CSS Columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkzqt/

```
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    columns: 10em; /* desired width of your column */
}

<div class="container">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That was what I was hoping. I just haven't managed to quite grasp how to use those, hence me asking. Think I managed to get it working now actually! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why do you have to set `height: 100%` on `html` and `body` as well? Doesn't seem to work without it, but not quite sure I understand what's going on here with the height setting...

Comment: By default, container type elements like html and body will be as tall as necessary to contain its children.  If you just specify it on the `.container` element, you're saying "be as tall as my parent".  For the html and body elements, the parent is the viewport, so `height: 100%` means "be as tall as the viewport".

Comment: Makes sense, although it seems to work without setting height on body and html now for some reason. Not sure why... I've only set the `columns` property of the container to 600px.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just have the divs inline beside each other and a horizontal scroll bar is going to appear at the bottom of the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>Col 1</div>
    <div>Col 2</div>
    <div>Col 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
#wrapper div {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-width:400px;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4k4PQ/)

Comment: Yes, but here you have 3 separate divs. What I mean is if you change your inner divs with paragraphs, add a lot more text in them and a lot more paragraphs. I want the text to flow down as normal until it hits bottom, and then wrap around to the top, continuing where it left off. I can't split it up into separate columns first, since that would be quite hard. No idea how big the browser window is, and with font sizes and line heights etc, it would be a pain :)

Comment: so you want the paragraph, no matter how long to run all the way to the right off the page?

Comment: I want the paragraphs, one after each other, run down until they hit the bottom of the window, and then continue at the top and for example 20% percent further to the right. And if it hits in the middle of a paragraph, the text should just continue at the top too, so the text is broken up. The whole paragraph shouldn't jump to the top. If avoidable.

Comment: Added a screen shot which hopefully clears up my intentions more :)